# Additional C++ bracket added in Visual Studio dissembly window?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, x86

I am looking at the Dissembly window in Visual Studio 2012 and I have the setting for interlacing C++ and generated ASM turned on. For this C++:

```
int main(){
    int h = my_func(6);
}
```

I get this ASM:

```
int main(){
 push        ebp  
 mov         ebp,esp  
 sub         esp,0CCh  
 push        ebx  
 push        esi  
 push        edi  
 lea         edi,[ebp-0CCh]  
 mov         ecx,33h  
 mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
 rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
    int h = my_func(4);
 push        4  
 call        my_func (0121159h)  
 add         esp,4  
 mov         dword ptr [h],eax  
}
 xor         eax,eax  
 pop         edi  
 pop         esi  
 pop         ebx  
 add         esp,0CCh  
 cmp         ebp,esp  
}                                         //What is this bracket??????
 call        __RTC_CheckEsp (01212E9h)  
 mov         esp,ebp  
 pop         ebp  
 ret
```

What is the odd bracket towards the end of the ASM? It doesn't have a corresponding bracket?

Comment: I've seen this many times and it's not just brackets, other source lines sometimes get repeated as well. I don't know the reason, but its probably a side effect of how VS compiler generates code internally.

Comment: @user2802841 if I were to remove the bracket does the surrounding asm look sensible?

Comment: I always guessed that it is the result of some inlining in action as inlining basically repeats code...

Comment: @pasztorpisti: No code is repeated here.  Only the source annotation is repeated.

Comment: @BenVoigt I see, but my assumption was inlining previously - although I've never did any research on these brackets. I think this is rather a "bug" in VS that could be sorted out somehow, it just isn't that critical/important.

Comment: @pasztorpisti: This case looks kinda weird, because there are no instruction groups intervening that belong to any other source line.  But in general **this behavior is not a bug** -- the optimizing compiler does break apart expressions and reorder operations for performance reasons, and then you get interleaving of parts of the behavior of source lines.  The compiler doesn't try to explain what part of the source line the instruction(s) correspond to.  So every partial line is annotated like a repeat of the entire line.

Comment: @BenVoigt Oh, got it! :-) It is more clear this way.

Comment: @BenVoigt Whats additionally interesting in this particular case is that if you set _Assembler Output_ to _Assembly With Source Code (/FAs)_ there is no repeat in `.asm` file.

Comment: @user2802841: I suppose that for the listing file, the compiler does an extra post-processing step of noticing when it has two blocks next to each other linked to the same source line, and combines them into one.  But this is just guesswork.

Comment: Or maybe the debugger disassembly has something special about the end of functions.  For example, there could be one source<->assembly mapping for use by single-stepping and run-to-cursor, and another for use by run-to-return.  More guesswork.  The only thing we know is that the instructions below the annotation map onto the source line above.

Comment: @BenVoigt Both of those seem like a probable candidates for explanation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you turn on the setting to include source line numbers in the interleaved listing, I think you'll see that both braces are the same, the end of the `main` function.

It's completely normal for one line of C++ code to generate more than one instruction, and it's not unusual for those instructions to appear in multiple non-consecutive blocks.  (In fact, when optimization is enabled, multiple blocks is the rule rather than the exception.)

This mixed listing contains the true machine code the compiler generated, expressed as assembly to make it easier to read.  The C++ snippets are annotations telling you why the compiler generated each bit of assembly.  The C++ snippets cannot be recombined into a complete C++ program.

Comment: Right you are Sir! I dont understand your explanation why it happened though?

Comment: @user997112: I'd need to know your compile options to have any chance of guessing the process the compiler went through to decide to generate multiple blocks for the function epilogue.